# Trying to display Json data from a web url into a table

Tags: javascript, html

```
"crops": [
{
  "Crop": "Red Beans", 
  "Date": "2018-Feb-28", 
  "Market": "Gulu", 
  "Price": "5002"
}, 
{
  "Crop": "Red Beans", 
  "Date": "2018-Feb-28", 
  "Market": "Busia", 
  "Price": "4889"
}, 
{
  "Crop": "Red Beans", 
  "Date": "2018-Feb-28", 
  "Market": "Kasese", 
  "Price": "5002"
}, 
{
  "Crop": "Red Beans", 
  "Date": "2018-Feb-28", 
  "Market": "Busia", 
  "Price": "4889"
}, 
{
  "Crop": "Red Beans", 
  "Date": "2018-Feb-28", 
  "Market": "Gulu", 
  "Price": "5002"
}, 
{
  "Crop": "Red Beans", 
  "Date": "2018-Feb-28", 
  "Market": "Kasese", 
  "Price": "4999"
}, 
{
  "Crop": "Red Beans", 
  "Date": "2018-Feb-28", 
  "Market": "Busia", 
  "Price": "4887"
}, 
{
  "Crop": "Red Beans", 
  "Date": "2018-Feb-28", 
  "Market": "Gulu", 
  "Price": "4999"
}
]}
```

Comment: You didn't provide any codes except json data, and you didn't decribe any issue/trouble you met.

Comment: congratulations, you've displayed it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved it

```
<?php
            try{
                $url = 'the json url goes here'; // path to your JSON file
                $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
                $characters = json_decode($data);
                echo '<div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 align="center">Market Prices for ';  echo $characters[0]->Crop;
                echo '</h3>
        </div>';
                echo '<div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover border" style="font-family: cambria">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Market</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';
                foreach ($characters as $character) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>' . $character->Market . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $character->Date . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $character->Price . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }

                echo '</tbody>
        </table>
    </div>';
            }
            catch (Exception $e){
                echo '<p align="center">No Internet Connection, please try again</p>';
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take this json and put it in the loop through length of the json and show data into the table.

Comment: The url for the json is https://agric-cart-api.herokuapp.com/beans,. i want to feed the data from the url into an html table